# Highlighting Section of an Image for Presentation

Tags: photo-editing

I'm trying to create a presentation that requires me highlighting sections in each photo. I mean having the rest of the image in a kind of transparent form but the section of interest should be very clear and emphasized so that the audience are drawn to that particular section of the image while still having the freedom to scan the overall image.

Thank you in anticipation of your help.

Comment: Hey olatunjee! If you decide to make a GD.SE account, we could give you a targeted answer if you tell us what software you have available.

Answer (score 3):

This will require a photo editing software. I don't know which one you uses so I'll explain the technique in general.

1. Open your photo and select the parts you don't want to emphasize - or
   select the other parts. You can use the "Invert" function to invert
   your selection when you done.
2. Copy the selected area and paste it as new layer in a new
   transparent image. Make sure the new image does not have a background (Transparent).
3. Set the opacity of the layer - this will create the fade effect.
4. Invert your selection the original photo and copy the rest of the
   image.
5. Paste it in the new image as new layer.
6. Save the image as PNG file.

Answer (score 2):

I cheated a bit but did it just in PowerPoint like this -

1. Place an image on screen as the background & note the position.
2. Copy & paste the image.
3. Set the new image to the same position.
4. Crop the front image as desired.
5. Change the settings on the 'rear' image in the format tab to lighten/darken/colour as necessary.

Ta-dah!  Slightly fiddly but easier to modify on the fly and no other software required so it can be tweaked on another machine if there's a problem on the day.

[image: Powerpoint selective image area (including racing pigs.)]